# "Add Features to Windows 8" menu missing

Tags: windows-8, windows-media-center

I have a Windows 8 Pro N x64 install and want to add der Media Center Feature Pack. Had anybody figured out how to do this?

I already tried **control /name Microsoft.WindowsAnytimeUpgrade** and nothing happens...

And no, searching for "Add Feature" and selecting "Settings" doesn't bring it up!!!

Comment: might help to have a screenshot showing what it actually saus

Comment: Can you check if you already have that feature though? That option disappeared after I installed the media center upgrade.

Comment: No MCE is not there.

Comment: Well, in my opinion in the N installs, MCE can't be installed because of no media player. They actually sell N versions? I thought they were "fake" versions to appease the EU

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We will start with what a Windows N version is:

> The N edition is for the European market. It comes without Windows Media Player. It is the result of a European lawsuit against Microsoft for bundling non-essential apps into the OS.

Answer to the problem seems to be its done broke:

> It appears that Microsoft **forgot** to put the "add features" options into the UK versions of windows 8 N.

Hopefully they fix this soon.

References:

http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_8-windows_install/windows-8-pro-add-features-to-windows-8-missing/1f6bd350-5bfb-4c10-bbf0-d0c6ba161b54

http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_8-windows_install/windows-8-pro-add-features-to-windows-8-missing/1f6bd350-5bfb-4c10-bbf0-d0c6ba161b54

UPDATE:

```
I finally called microsoft and tech support confirmed you 
cannot add media center to Windows 8 Pro N. 

FYI - one could add media center to Windows 7 Premium N 
so this a regressive behaviour for an 'upgrade'.
```

(Last Answer)
http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_8-windows_install/no-add-features-to-windows-8-option-media-center/10968a9a-1ce0-43c1-a2f1-93cc5eb31283?page=2

Answer (score 1):

I don't know for the N version but on my Win 8 Pro I did once the "Add Feature" thing to add Media Center but when I reboot it did not appeared. I had to go back in the "Program and Features" link in the control panel and select "Turn Windows Feature On/Off" and I saw that a new item was present : Media Features --> Windows Media Center.

Hope it will help!

Comment: No as already mentioned, this does not matter, there are differences between N, K and Normal versions and it seems that this based on that.

Answer (score 0):

Try downloading Media Feature Pack 
http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=30685

Answer (score -2):

http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows-8/feature-packs

This should be your solution. If it still doesn't answer your question then I don't believe there's an answer.

Comment: "The Media Feature Pack for N and KN versions of Windows 8 will install Media Player and related technologies on a computer running Windows 8 N or Windows 8 KN editions." and nothing more, I want to install the Media Center Feature Pack!

Comment: @TobiasHerkula Maybe it's a prerequisite?

Comment: @TobiasHerkula check the new solution.

Comment: I already have the Media Feature Pack installed, so I have the Media Player but MCE ist still missing, and no the steps to install it doesn't help, if I search for "add features" the menu isn't there.